# ID en una tabla se altera

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla en mysql, la cual al momento de insertar desde PHP altera el orden lógico del ID:

```
"INSERT INTO `persona` (`id_persona`, `nombre_contacto`, `apellido_contacto`,
                           `telefono_persona`, `email_persona`, `documento`,
                           `horaEntrada`, `horaSalida`, `usuario`, `password`,
                           `tipo_documento`, `id_ciudad_persona`, `id_estado_persona`, `empresa_per`,
                           `id_tipoUsuario`, `id_usuario_punto`, `dependencia_persona`)
                            VALUES (NULL, '$nombre ', '$apellido', NULL, NULL, '$documentoIdentidad',
                                    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '$id_empresa', '5', NULL, '$tipoDependencia')"
```

---

-----------Insert desde PHPmyAdmin se comporta bien, siguiendo el orden logico.

```
00000000113             
00000000114             
00000000115          
00000000116
```

-----------Altera cuando se realiza desde PHP

```
00000000118  
00000000120
00000000122
```

¿A qué se puede deber esta anomalía?

Comment: pero que id se modifica porque hay muchos y no especificas

Comment: Que tipo de dato es el ID?

Comment: Con la información tan "exacta" que das, solo Dios lo sabe amigo.

Comment: Dudo que el problema sea de tu tabla de mysql, debe de ser de tu código PHP para insertar en la base de datos, te recomiendo editar tu pregunta con éste código.

Comment: Solo puede haber un AI, el cual es de la PK(tengo entendido)

Comment: @Gabriel traté de ser muy breve para evaluar posibles causas, sin necesidad de poner todo el codigo completo, el cual es muy extenso, pero gracias por la correccion

Comment: @Kevinsalazar No uses las respuestas para escribir comentarios. Cuando tengas la suficiente reputación podrás comentar en todas las publicaciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu ID que es llave primaria es incrementar no es necesario que lo mandes como null, ni siquiera necesitas hacer mención de el, solo quilato de tu código:

```
"INSERT INTO `persona` (`nombre_contacto`, `apellido_contacto`,
                           `telefono_persona`, `email_persona`, `documento`,
                           `horaEntrada`, `horaSalida`, `usuario`, `password`,
                           `tipo_documento`, `id_ciudad_persona`, `id_estado_persona`, `empresa_per`,
                           `id_tipoUsuario`, `id_usuario_punto`, `dependencia_persona`)
                            VALUES ('$nombre ', '$apellido', NULL, NULL, '$documentoIdentidad',
                                    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '$id_empresa', '5', NULL, '$tipoDependencia')"
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razon!